# Show that the free product of countably many countable groups is countable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

The question I am struggling with is as follows:

> Suppose that $\{G_\alpha\}$ is a countable collection of countable
>   groups. Show that $\ast_{\alpha}G_\alpha$ is countable.

The definition of countable that I am using is that $G$ there is some injective function $G \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

I am aware that one can show the Cartesian product of countable groups is countable by constructing a matrix, and I have been trying to do something similar for this problem, however I can't seem to get anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at most $\;\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0\;$ *finite* words that can be formed out of the elements of each group $\;G_\alpha\;$ .

Every word in that free product is the concatenation of a **finite** number of words ( namely, from a *finite* subset of $\;\{G_\alpha\}$ ) .

Thus, we have at most
$$\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0\;\;\text {words in}\;\;*_\alpha G_\alpha$$

Comment: Can you clarify what $N_0$ is in this case?

Comment: The cardinality of the natural numers...or of the rationals, or of the integers or of any *countable* infinite set, of course. Haven't you studied yet some basic set theory? Because free products is a somewhat advanced subject in group theory which usually comes *after* set theory. And it is "aleph null", with aleph being the first letter in the hebrew alphabet. This is a universal notation.